# Is it possible to use inverse kinematics and Quaternions in Blender?

Tags: rigging, transforms, bones

Is it possible to use IK bones to update quaternion rotation values in Blender?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can insert a keyframe and use 'Visual Rotation', this uses the pose with constraints applied, to set the rotation of the pose bones.

Note that if all you want is the quaternion values (without applying keyframes), Python can get the final matrix can calculate them.