# Armature bone rotation values not changing when using inverse kinematics

Tags: armature, bones, drivers, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to have drivers activate based on certain bone rotation values. However when the bones are moved as a result of the IK setup their rotation values do not change at all.

Edit:

[File](https://mega.nz/file/SBkCUTaS#f1Gsn5eTEojAt1xca1xWGWg6-WLyyxSbI0W8eDiJ_AI)

Shoulder_DV_.L should move when the Hand_IK_.L is.

Comment: Can you share your blend file?  It's easier to figure out what is not working if we can see it.

Comment: File link added

Answer (score 0):

So let's look at one driven bone:

[image]

Here, Spine01 is getting a Y quaternion driver based on the Z quaternion component of Core_IK.  I've rotated Core_IK a bit, and showed Spine01's transform in the sidebar, so that you can see that, yes, the driver is actually working-- that Y rotation field is non-zero, and since Core_IK's Z component is -0.082, it's doing what you told it to.

But unfortunately, doing what you told it to do, is doing nothing.  Why?  The short answer is that the Y component is the only component you're changing.  With quaternions, increasing the Y component alone is not the same thing as rotating in the local Y axis.

Quaternions are kind of weird.  Even though Blender lets you deal with their components individually, they're not really four separate numbers; quaternions are normalized, four-dimensional vectors.  If you want Spine01 to rotate, you need to also change at least the W component as well as the Y.  How much?  Well, (w^2 + Y^2)^0.5 = 1.  So, that's why they taught you algebra way back when, for this moment.

Other driven bones in the armature have similar issues.

What should you do?  You should change the rotation mode of the bones that you want driven to be Euler bones.  You can specify the rotation mode in properties/bone/transform/mode.  If you do that, your individual channels *will* represent rotation in a particular axis.  In the case of Spine01, which looks like you're only ever going to use drivers to control its roll, there's no advantage to quaternions over Eulers anyways.  The advantages to quaternion interpolation are only ever apparent when a bone rotates in more than one Euler axis.

Is there anything else you should change?  Yes.  Just as the Y quat component of Spine01 doesn't rotate anything, the Z quat component of Core_IK is not a very useful input to drive this rotation.  Here, you don't need to change the rotation mode of anything, you just need to change how Blender reads whatever transform you give it, by changing the mode in the "rot" variable for your driver.  You can leave Core_IK as a quaternion bone and still read its orientation as an Euler for purposes of rotating Spine01.

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding Quaternion and Euler. Unfortunately that doesn't resolve my issue. When the Hand_IK_.L bone is moved it results in the UpperarmTwist01_.L bone moving which should trigger the Shoulder_DV_.L driver but it does not because UpperarmTwist01_.L's values never change. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Ralthkon The driver you're talking about works.  Rotate the tiwst bone and you'll see the shoulder bone move.  But you will never have any rotation of any sort on the driver bone without doing it manually, because it is not involved in the IK chain.  The IK chain is the forearm and the upper arm.  As the child of upper arm, upperarmtwist acquires no *local space* rotation unless you give it some manually.

Comment: Ah, ok that makes sense regarding the IK chain. But then shouldn't upperarm.l have it's values change since it's part of the ik chain?

Comment: @Ralthkon Its post-constraint transform-- its transform channel-- will change from IK, but you don't have anything being driven by upperarm.l in that file.  The numbers displayed on the sidebar will not change, because those are the raw transforms, pre-constraints.  Any more questions, you need a new, specific question-- comments aren't the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with somewhat the same issue and this helped:

[Is it possible to use inverse kinematics and Quaternions in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/11048/is-it-possible-to-use-inverse-kinematics-and-quaternions-in-blender/11056)

So in short, whether you're using Quaternion or Euler, when you insert a keyframe with 'Visual Rotations' it applies the constraints (including IK) and thus rotation values get updated.